# Can not add pydal submodule in web2py project

Tags: git, web2py, git-submodules, pydal

I am starting a new web project with python and I wanted to use web2py framework. But I had some problems in git setup.

I have downloaded web2py source from its website, created my own git repository. Unzip everything in my repository folder. When I tried to

```
git add .
```

I get

```
fatal: Not a git repository: gluon/packages/dal/../../../.git/modules/gluon/packages/dal
```

So after some search on internet I found out this folder is a submodule in web2py repository. And there is a solution if I clone everything recursively from their repository. But I do not want to clear all my repository and start from scratch.

Is there a way to register gluon/packages/dal directory as a submodule of my project?

p.s. I've already tried the solution on [How to add already cloned projects as submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725107/how-to-add-already-cloned-projects-as-submodules) and it did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem last night.
You don't need clear your repository only for this.  Simply download source zip of `pydal` from [here](https://github.com/web2py/pydal), rename the folder name from `pydal` to `dal`, and replace `/gluon/packages/dal` folder by it.  It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to delete the .git file from **dal** folder. later on

```
git init
```

then

```
git add libs/
```